# handler doesn't update UI after ondestroy()

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, handler

I have a Handler declared as a global variable in an activity. That handler receives messages from a thread and updates de UI.

Everything is working ok until the app is sent to the background, onDestroy is called.

When I go back to the app, the thread keeps sending messages to the handler, it makes the changes on the UI, but those changes are not shown anymore.

I don't want to stop the thread after onpause, because it has to be up to read some info I need even when the app is on background.

How can I get this working?

This is the handler declared as global variable:

```
Handler hRefreshData=new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        edText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textarea2);
        edText2.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
        edText2.setTextSize(20);
        edText2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        edText2.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < tag_db_index; i++) {
            if (tag_db[i].getActive() == TRUE) {
                edText2.append("[" + i + "]\t");
                edText2.append("ANT " + tag_db[i].tag.getAntenna() + "\t");
                edText2.append("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the thread, started when the user press the button read:

```
    thrRead = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (bRunningRead) {

                // El siguiente método realiza sólo lectura (la conexión ya está abierta)
                aReadTags = lectura();
                processTags();
                try{
                    semaforo.acquire();
                    copyaReadTags();
                    semaforo.release();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {

                }

                Message m = new Message();
                if (bRunningRead)
                    hRefreshData.sendMessage(m);

            }

        }
    };
    thrRead.start();
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You should perform background tasks on a service, alarm, or job, and have the activity request/listen for updates on the task whenever is visible. You are using the wrong mechanism to accomplish the task

Comment: Read about how tondo background tasks in Android. There is lots of information online.

Comment: ok, I can move the thread code to a Service, but I don't know how to listen for updates on the task, could you tell me what should I use to do that so I can find info about it?

Comment: yes, move the thread code to a Service and read about "bound [local] service" pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with threads. I don't use the handler, instead of it, I have used a broadcastreceiver. The global variables I need, I save them in the Application level so I don't lose them when onDestroy is called in the activity.